# Rotate sprite to face a point (cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I seem to be having an issue with calculating the angle between my sprite and a touch point. I'm trying to get my sprite to directly face the direction of the touch point whenever the user touches the screen. Here's my code:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint tapPosition;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches){
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        tapPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location]];
    }

    float angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpAngle(fish.position, tapPosition));
    [fish runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:angle]];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the end of Nikhil's answer to avoid getting a negative angle when the touch location is to the bottom right of the sprite.

```
if (calculatedAngle < 0) 
{
     calculatedAngle+=360;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out, first of all you don't need that for loop because you are just going to end up with the last touch location anyway. You may as well use [touches anyObject] as below.

Second, I am not sure what ccpAngle does off the top of my head but when macros like that don't work sometimes its easier to just do the maths yourself.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint tapPosition;
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
   tapPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location]];

   float dY = fish.position.y - tapPosition.y;
   float dX = fish.position.x - tapPosition.x;
   float offset = dX<0 ? 90.0f : -90.0f;
   float angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2f(dY, dX)) + offset;

   [fish runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:angle]];
}
```

You probably could replace dX and dY with a point from ccpDiff as well but it doesn't really matter. Also depending on where the head of your fish is you may need to adjust the angle offset but I will leave that up to you.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the try. I tried plugging your code in, to no avail. It seems the rotation is just wonky. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I need more details, what actually happened?

Comment: It rotates when the screen is tapped, but not to the correct angle. Sometimes its not very close to correct in the angle

Comment: It's impossible to work out what is wrong without seeing it. Try logging the angle and then tap around where you know the what the angle should be, for example 0. You should see what the offset should be.

Comment: I gave it a look, for some reason its off by 266 degrees. So I just modified it to angle:266-angle. Pretty random, I think it may be preventing the sprite from rotating to face one side as well (the right side it follows correctly, but the left side, the rear of the sprite rotates towards the point)

Comment: You can change the offset for each side in the offset line dx<0 ? -90 : 90; if the left side is wrong you need to change the -90 to something else.

Answer (score 3):

CCPoint pos1 = [fish position];
CCPoint pos2 = touchlocation;

```
float theta = atan((pos1.y-pos2.y)/(pos1.x-pos2.x)) * 180 * 7 /22;

float calculatedAngle;

if(pos1.y - pos2.y > 0)
{
    if(pos1.x - pos2.x < 0)
    {
        calculatedAngle = (-90-theta);
    }
    else if(pos1.x - pos2.x > 0)
    {
       calculatedAngle = (90-theta);
    }       
}
else if(pos1.y - pos2.y < 0)
{
    if(pos1.x - pos2.x < 0)
    {
       calculatedAngle = (270-theta);
    }
    else if(pos1.x - pos2.x > 0)
    {
       calculatedAngle = (90-theta);
    }
}
```

Use this calculatedAngle in your Run Action.. hope this helps... :)